# shared stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have many sql server databases which have exactly the same schema. Is there any place where I can write a stored procedure and apply for all databases? If I create the stored procedure for each database, when needed, I have to update them all.

Comment: You could create a separate database called "Shared" and then just put those stored procs there and execute them using `exec Shared.dbo.StoredProcName`

Answer (score 6):

You can create a stored procedure in `master` that runs in the current database context *if* you prefix  the stored procedure with `sp`. Here's an example:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE Test1  --for demo purposes
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_DoStuff
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT DB_NAME()
GO

USE Test1
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_DoStuff
GO

USE msdb
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_DoStuff
GO

USE master
GO
DROP DATABASE Test1
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_DoStuff
GO
```

This of course is why you don't normally create user stored procs with starting `sp`... the engine attempts to resolve the name in master

You can rely on deferred name resolution to not throw an error for your non-existent tables in master

Answer (score 1):

The issue you'll run into is table bindings -- how will the sproc know which database to call?  So you'll probably want to use **marc_s**'s comment plus some dynamic SQL where you pass in the database name (and username) to the shared sproc.

```
create proc GetAllWidgets @dbname sysname, @owner nvarchar(100)
as
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) 
set @sql = 'select * from [' + @dbname + '].[' + @owner + '].Widget'
sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm actually aware of this way of doing. I just thought I may be missing something big (like it may be possible through extended stored procedure or clr stored procedure etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a central management server and run your alter/create script against multiple servers at the same time.[See msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934126.aspx)

Comment: So, there are still a stored proc per each db, but I can update them all at once, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.sp_YourProc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT DB_NAME()EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'ForEach';
END
GO
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sp_YourProc';
```